# É possível executar código sem ser de front-end no stackoverflow?

Tags: novo-recurso

Me deparei com algumas perguntas relacionadas a Java, PHP, etc. Queria saber quais linguagens é possível executar aqui na comunidade. Se não for possível, esta seria uma ótima funcionalidade.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Não, por isso usamos outros sites pra ajudar nisso, como [ideone](https://ideone.com/), [repl.it](https://repl.it/), [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/), [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/), e outros.